# strange behavior in foreach statement (extra loops)

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events",$db);
$rowcheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $allevents = array();
    echo "<br>Display events: ($rowcheck)";
    $i = '0';
while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $allevents[] = $row_user;

    foreach ($allevents as $val) {
        $eventID = $val['event_ID'];

        echo "<br>$eventID";

        echo "End foreach.";
    }  // end foreach events as val


    echo "End While.";
} // end while
print_r($allevents);
```

And get the following output:

```
Display events: (3)  
ID 1 End foreach.End While.  
ID 1 End foreach.  
ID 2 End foreach.End While.  
ID 1 End foreach.  
ID 2 End foreach.  
ID 3 End foreach.End While. 
Array (   
 [0] => Array (  
   [event_ID] => 1  
   [eventtype] => 1  
   [eventlocation] => 1  
   [eventhostfamily] => 23  
   [eventturn] => 459  
   [char1] => 9  
   [char2] => 19 
 )  
 [1] => Array (  
   [event_ID] => 2  
   [eventtype] => 4  
   [eventlocation] => 1  
   [eventhostfamily] => 29  
   [eventturn] => 461  
   [char1] => 208  
   [char2] => 0 
 )  
 [2] => Array (  
   [event_ID] => 3  
   [eventtype] => 4  
   [eventlocation] => 1  
   [eventhostfamily] => 28  
   [eventturn] => 462  
   [char1] => 1  
   [char2] => 0 
 ) 
)
```

For some reason that I cannot fathom, its giving me some weird loop where it returns the 1st row, then the first two rows, then the first three rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending each row from mysql to your array and then output the whole array. Move the foreach loop out of your while:

```
while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $allevents[] = $row_user;
    echo "End While.";
} // end while

foreach ($allevents as $val) {
    $eventID = $val['event_ID'];

    echo "<br>$eventID";

    echo "End foreach.";
}  // end foreach events as val
```